# How to do Commit and Rollback If Insert command or update command  in for loop using c# in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

Can any body explain this scenario..

I know using one insert or update or any command with out for loop we can do commit and rollback if any errors in the data.

But my doubt is if i have insert command or update command  in for loop then when will do commit or rollback.

Comment: If your are doing this with LINQ you can either user Transaction Scope or also put the SubmitChanges after completion of iteration.

Comment: Thanks your reply.. am not using LINQ. i am using sql quary(ADO.Net).

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this

```
//Start transaction here
bool isSuccess = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    try
    {
        //your Insert/update Query
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isSuccess = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (isSuccess)
{
    //Commit transaction 
}
else
{
   //Roll back transaction
}
```

But my suggestion would be to use a different approach

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    //Build your Insert/Update query here
    //Note : do not execute it yet
}

//Start transaction
try
{
    //Execute the query here
    //Commit transaction 
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //Roll back transaction
}
```

In the first case you will be locking the tables until your whole for loop is completed which may also contain business logic, but in the second case you will be inside a transaction only for the part that is required(the Insert/Update part)

Comment: i used first case. In if condion i kept commit command.But i am getting this error.........This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.Can you explain...

Comment: can you update the question with the code you have tried, so that i can check it